# What is Windows trying to tell me with this dialog?

Tags: windows

I have this zero-size dialog: what is windows trying to ask me?  I was away from my desk and I see this when I sit back down.  Any ways to resize it?

[image]

Ctrl-C, Ctrl-V worked.

```
[Window Title]
Microsoft Windows

[Main Instruction]
Logitech LVPrcSrv Module. stopped working and was closed

[Content]
A problem caused the application to stop working correctly. Windows will notify you if a solution is available.

[Close]
```

Looks like my Logitech webcam drivers died.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> on it, and then <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> in notepad (for instance)?

If it's a messagebox, you will see the text it contains.

Answer (score 3):

Try typing <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>space</kbd> and selecting 'Size' (or typing <kbd>s</kbd>). That should let you resize the dialog if possible.

**Edit:** obviously, the dialog needs focus - click on it's title bar before pressing alt-space

**Edit 2:** Also that looks like the [Windows Problem Reports and Solutions](http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/2006/10/vista-problem-reports-and-solutions.html) icon. You should be able to open it from Control Panel and get some information on what happened.

Answer (score 0):

From the icon it looks like an popup for the Solution and Error wizard. You should be able to go to control panel for this and find the message.